# jQuery: Retrieving a Field whose id is dynamically generated

Tags: jquery

I am running JSF 3.1, alongside SEAM 2.  I have a simple function that sets the name of a field.  However, the field is dynmically generated on the page in form '{pagePrefix}':editFormId:field:clentName , where 'pagePrefix' is a locally defined variable.  How do add the said variable as a String on jQuery call?

Currently this causes all my fields that have the prefix to have their value set to clientName.

```
function setName(clientName) {

            var prefix = jQuery("#{idPrefix}");         
            var nameInput = jQuery("#" + prefix + "\\:editFormId\\:selectedClientField\\:selectedClientName");
            nameInput.val(clientName);
    }
```

Comment: locally defined in what sense?

Comment: @stevemarvell The page gets a param passed to it called idPrefix

Comment: And `{variable}` is the convention for rendering it? What template system is rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you template system renders variables using `{variable}` then all you want is:

```
function setName(clientName) {

        var prefix = "{idPrefix}";         
        var nameInput = jQuery("#" + prefix + "\\:editFormId\\:selectedClientField\\:selectedClientName");
        nameInput.val(clientName);
}
```

OR

```
function setName(clientName) {

        var nameInput = jQuery("#{idPrefix}\\:editFormId\\:selectedClientField\\:selectedClientName");
        nameInput.val(clientName);
}
```

Comment: The first solution seems to have the same effect on my code as I'm currently having, and the second seems to be retrieving something, though the nothing happens on the UI

Comment: you'll have to explain what template system you're using so I can update

Comment: I am running JSF 3.1, alongside SEAM 2

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with them.

Comment: It turns out my retrieval of idPrefix was wrong, the first solution does indeed work.